# Can I detect a click on an <i> tag in back-end with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, click, font-awesome

I'm using asp.net and I have an `<i>` tag which is used as a button. Can I directly, in the back-end (.vb file), have it call a click function?

Front-end:

```
<i class='fa fa-check edit-profile-btns saveprofile' id="saveProfileTextbox1" runat="server"></i>
```

Back-end:

```
 Protected Sub btn_saveProfile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveProfileTextbox1.Click
     'do something
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why not remove the runat=server and wrap it inside a LinkButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to try to get an `<i>` tag to act like a button, but they all get pretty messy and are not advised.

As @VDWWD suggested, and in my experience, it's best to wrap the `<i>` tag in a `asp:LinkButton`, particularly if you want to use font-awesome (a regular `asp:Button` won't display the font in most cases)

**So it would look something like this:**

*Front-end*

```
<asp:linkButton Text="<i class='fa fa-check edit-profile-btns saveprofile' </i>" ID="lbtnSaveProfile" runat="server" CssClass="someclass" /> 

'OR because intellisense doesn't read the text property,
'you may prefer to do it this way:

<asp:linkButton ID="lbtnSaveProfile" runat="server" CssClass="someclass" ><i class="fa fa-check edit-profile-btns saveprofile" </i></asp:linkButton>
```

*Back-end*

```
Protected Sub lbtnSaveProfile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnSaveProfile.Click
    Try
        'do something
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how your CSS is set up, so you may need figure out if you need the `saveprofile` class in the `<i>` tag or the `asp:LinkButton`.

I hope that works for you. =)